# .htaccess redirect get to a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect a link from
    `www.example.com/ex.php?name=andy`
to
    `www.andy.example.com`
Can you give me the code please

Answer (score 0):

Why use .htaccess? You can do that with PHP.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.'. $_GET['name'] .'.example.com';

header('Location: '. $url);
?>
```

Just make sure you don't output any text before using header().

To get the name from the subdomain URL do the following.

```
<?php
$new_url = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$url_parts = explode('.', $new_url);

echo 'Name is: '. $url_parts[0];
?>
```

james.example.com results in "Name is: james".

Comment: yes... but i still want to be able to get the name trought get when i am on the subdomain

Comment: You can use $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] for that and then explode that string on the dot and get the name from the resulting array.